# Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3rd edition, Chapter 9: Failed test on users_edit_test.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am consistently receiving three errors and I have no idea why. I'm following the tutorial to the best of my ability, and I have scoured through Chapter 9 for mistakes and I haven't seen any. Running `bundle exec rake test`. I get the three following errors:

```
FAIL["test_unsuccessful_edit", UsersEditTest, 2015-08-22 09:09:06 +0900]
 test_unsuccessful_edit#UsersEditTest (1440202146.96s)
        expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
        test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'

 FAIL["test_successful_edit", UsersEditTest, 2015-08-22 09:09:06 +0900]
 test_successful_edit#UsersEditTest (1440202146.97s)
        expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
        test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'

 FAIL["test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding", UsersEditTest, 2015-08-22 09:09:07 +0900]
 test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding#UsersEditTest (1440202147.07s)
        Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/762146111/edit> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/>.
        Expected "http://www.example.com/users/762146111/edit" to be === "http://www.example.com/".
        test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'
```

As you can see, all of my errors can be found in test/integration/users_edit_test. Two of my tests fail in the same way, with this message: `expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>`. Line 12 and 25 has the same code:

```
assert_template 'users/edit'
```

Line 43 has the following code:

```
assert_redirected_to edit_user_path(@user)
```

I have a _header.html.erb file with a link that is supposed to go to the user's edit page but it just redirects to the index. I have a file app/views/users/edit.html.erb so I don't know why it isn't showing up. Here is the code for the settings link:

`<li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>`

Here is my code for my users_controller.rb file. I suspect the problem is my `correct_user` method not firing like it is supposed to. (By the way, I have tried commenting out the code inside the "edit" method, but the problem still persists.)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # debugger
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
          redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  #  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id].destroy)
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #  redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user?(@user)  
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

In app/helpers/sesions_helper.rb I have two methods, `current_user` and `current_user?`

```
def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end

def current_user
    if(user_id = session[:user_id])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
            log_in user
            @current_user = user
        end
    end
end
```

Here is the config/routes file:

```
root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
```

I suspect the answer to my issue is super easy, but I've no idea what is wrong. Here is the users_edit_test.rb file

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
#    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: '',
                                    email: 'foo@invalid',
                                    password: 'foo',
                                    password_confirmation: 'bar' }
    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end


  test "successful edit" do
#    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    name = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: name,
                                    email: email,
                                    password: '',
                                    password_confirmation: '' }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal @user.name, name
    assert_equal @user.email, email
  end

  test "successful edit with friendly forwarding" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
#    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to edit_user_path(@user)
    name = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: name,
                    email: email,
                    password: 'foobar',
                    password_confirmation: 'foobar' }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal @user.name, name
    assert_equal @user.email, email
  end
end
```

Comment: Please update your question with the `test/integration/users_edit_test.rb` file's content.

Comment: Why is the @user in the edit method commented out?

Comment: @engineerDave because the correct_user method, which gets run before the edit method, performs the same task when using the edit or update methods.

Comment: @LesPaul did you try my answer? It looks like what I suspected, you have commented out `log_in_as(@user)` line your test and that's why it's failing. Please try my answer and let me know! It should fix your problem. Let me know if not.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam yes and it still wouldn't pass. the first thing I tried was placing the log_in_as(@user) at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 4):

Although, you did not upload your `users_edit_test.rb` file here, I actually read the [chapter 9](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#code-unsuccessful_edit_test) from the book you mentioned and then also got the source code from its [github repo](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition).

So, I was running the same test as yours (`bundle exec rake test test/integration/users_edit_test.rb`) locally and it's passing fine. There is no test failure. But, I figured out that, if the `log_in_as(@user)` is missing from the `test "unsuccessful edit"` test, then it fails with the exact same error message that you posted here. And, that makes sense, because, if you don't have `log_in_as(@user)` i.e. logged_in user, then it can't render the edit page for that user and hence gets this error:

```
expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
```

So, I am pretty sure that you have missed that part while typing it from the tutorial.

Here is the **full working version (all tests are passing)** of the `users_edit_test.rb`file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: "",
                                    email: "user@invalid",
                                    password:              "foo",
                                    password_confirmation: "bar" }
    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end

  test "successful edit with friendly forwarding" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to edit_user_path(@user)
    name  = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name:  name,
                                    email: email,
                                    password:              "",
                                    password_confirmation: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name,  @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end
end
```

Just copy this and replace your current file's content with this. Then, all tests will pass.

Comment: I tried exactly what you said and I receive the same errors.

Comment: Well, you have some other typo/missing parts somewhere else then. Because, its perfectly passing for me in my computer. So, we have to figure out where you are missing something.

Comment: So, after replacing the file, you still get all 3 errors as before?

Comment: No, I get two errors because you didn't have the test "successful edit", but the two errors I received were the same as before.

Comment: OK great, so now you get 2 errors instead of 3? Which means we made some progress. Now you are getting 2 errors in `successful edit`?

Comment: No you misunderstood, your file only had two tests and not three, so I only got two errors because you didn't have a third test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87639/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-les-paul).

Answer (score 1):

I'm working through this tutorial now as well, and I got the tests to pass just fine, so I'm comparing my tests to yours and you need to make the following changes:

1. In `successful test` and `unsuccessful test`, put `log_in_as(@user)` before `get edit_user_path(@user)`.
2. In `successful test with friendly forwarding`, do just the opposite: put `log_in_as(@user)` **after** `get edit_user_path(@user)`.
3. In your users_controller.rb file, check your private `correct_user` method:

   ```
   redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user?(@user)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
   ```

Making those changes and re-running the test suite should make your tests pass.

Answer (score 1):

I'm following same tutorial and I got the same error:

```
  expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
```

I've solved it just with a switch of position of this block:

```
  test "unsuccesful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: "", 
                                    email: "invalid@invalid",
                                    password: "foo",
                                    password_confirmation: "bar" }
    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end
```

and this one:

```
  test "successful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    name = "Name"
    email = "valid@valid.com"
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: name, 
                                    email: email,
                                    password: "",
                                    password_confirmation: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name, @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end
```

Actually now it works in any order I put the two blocks.. I know it doesn't have any sense but maybe it's linked with some strange behaviour of cut&paste on Cloud9 (the cloud-based IDE which the author suggest to use).

Answer (score 1):

Make your *users.yml* is well defined and there's not a typo over it. I had a typo, and was getting the same error.

Error (notice the upper E in the email)

```
michael:
  name: michael Example
  email: michael@Example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Well defined

```
michael:
  name: michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working through the tutorial, too. I had some similar issues.

If I understand correctly `<[]>` indicates a redirect that the test browser hasn't yet followed. I would put a `debugger` right before the failing assertion and inspect the situation from there. In my case a forgotten `follow_redirect!` or an `assert_template` instead of an `assert_redirected_to` was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I went into the same problem.
In my case it turned out that I changed the password for the user in the fixture **user.yml**.

After several hours, I found that there MUST be STRONG alignement between:

1. user.yml
2. test_helper.rb2.
3. the database (where the digest is stored)

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still having this error i was able to get through it by changing the user in the def setup to another user from the users.yml.